# Is it possible to bind a method at runtime?

Tags: methods, go

I have the following construct:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar func(foo *Foo) bool
}
```

Because `Bar` is not really a method, it accepts `Foo` as parameter (like `self` in Python's bound methods). I'd however bind it to the struct as a method if there was an easy way. I suspect I could using reflection, but I want to keep it trivial. Is there a trick to bind a function to a struct? How would you do it?

Edit: I'll add a concrete example of what I'm doing.

```
type Route struct {
    Matcher func(route *Route, r *http.Request) bool
}
```

Route accepts a custom `Matcher` function. If not set, a default matcher function is set when the route is registered:

```
func (mux *ServeMux) HandleRoute(r Route) {
    // ...

    // Set default matcher.
    if r.Matcher == nil {
        r.Matcher = mux.RouteMatcher
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then that function is used to do a matching:

```
func (mux *ServeMux) Match(r *http.Request) Route {
    // ...

    if route.Matcher(&route, r) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

The function is not bound to the route. My question is if this is a reasonable/idiomatic way to set a custom callable, or if there is a trick to make the function "bound" to the struct as a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't explain what you are trying to accomplish. What is wrong with this?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct{}

func (f *Foo) Bar() bool {
    return true
}

func main() {
    var f Foo
    fmt.Println(f.Bar())
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type BarFunc func(foo *Foo) bool

type Foo struct {
    BarFunc
}

func (f *Foo) Bar() bool {
    return f.BarFunc(f)
}

func UserBarFunc(foo *Foo) bool { return true }

func main() {
    var f Foo
    f.BarFunc = UserBarFunc
    fmt.Println(f.Bar())
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, but this is a little different. One of my struct fields is a user defined function. The question is if it is trivial to bind an external function as a method.

Comment: The second example is what I'm doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to bind a new method at runtime. The compiler needs to know what methods a type has at compile time. Consider this code:

```
package main

import "rand"

type Foo struct {}

type Bar interface {
    Baz()
}

func main() {
    if rand.Intn(2) != 0 {
        // code to bind method Baz to Foo at runtime
    }

    var f Foo

    // Should this compile? It depends on whether or not the if
    // statement above ran, which can only be known at runtime.
    f.Baz()

    // Same here. The compiler can't know whether or not f has
    // a method Baz.
    var b Bar = f
}
```

Your example code looks like a reasonable way to do what you want. PeterSO's answer presents another way to do it that makes the function look more like a regular method.

Comment: I added a concrete example of what I'm doing.

Comment: Thank you. Accepted his answer because of the alternative implementation, you get a +1. ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a helper method with the desired name (`Bar`) that chooses and calls the desired function at runtime?

Comment: That doesn't change what I'm doing. I can simply continue to accept a custom method with the desired signature.